# How to show list of user properties values with event count on firebase analytics console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Previously we were used Google Analytics and it shows list of user phone number inside custom report as custom dimension. Like this how to show list of user phone number as user properties on Firebase analytics console.

```
//sending user phone number as an event.
Bundle userPhone=new Bundle()
userPhone.putString("UserPhone",USER_PHONE_NUMBER);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("NewUser",userPhone);
```

I expect list of user phone number inside NewUser event on firebase console

Comment: what you are asking about ? didn't your log event showing in firebase console? \

Comment: Events are showing correctly, but i want list of phone number which are i am passing as bundle with an event. It was possible in Google Analytics.

Comment: it still possible in Firebase and you are doing in a right way

Comment: make sure that data you are passing is not null and also check log selecting verbose type to check if logging happing in right way and then from firebase panel you can see your log with mobile number

Comment: some time it is possible that firebase log take little but time to update and also make sure you have created parameter in selection of analytics log

Comment: sorry but, I am not getting list of phone number anywhere on firebase console, I am trying for this from couple of weeks. Please help